# MySQL view: How to create a view returning columns from parent table (id, name) and sum of related items from child table?

Tags: mysql, view

How to create a view returning columns from parent table (`id`, `name`) and **sum** of related items from child table ?

I have two tables:

```
table 'parent':
| id | name |
|  1 |  foo |
|  2 |  bar |

table 'child':
| id | parent_id | unit_price | quantity |
|  1 |         1 |         25 |        2 |
|  2 |         1 |         10 |        5 |
|  4 |         2 |         50 |        2 |
|  5 |         2 |        100 |        4 |
```

The view would look like this:

```
| parent_id | name | total |
|         1 |  foo |   100 |
|         2 |  bar |   500 |
```

Not sure if it's useful for the view, but parent_id is a foreign key.

Or is it better to use triggers in such case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a view using a join to find the sums:

```
CREATE VIEW yourView AS
SELECT
    p.id AS parent_id,
    p.name,
    SUM(COALESCE(c.unit_price * c.quantity, 0)) AS total
FROM parent p
LEFT JOIN child c
    ON p.id = c.parent_id
GROUP BY
    p.id, p.name;
```